# Change username login to Email login

Tags: joomla

I use joomla's default login module. The module asks for username and password at the time of login. I want it to change it to Email and Password. Where do i change the code for it to happen. I use Joomla 1.5.21 . Any help is appreciated

Thanks and Regards
Sanjai

Comment: You should also upgrade to 1.5.22, it's a security release.

Answer (score 4):

there is already a extension module for that purpose. I think it is much easier this way. You can find more info about it here:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/authentication/10343

If you prefer to do it yourself, then you have to look into couple of different folders:
**joomla_root/modules/login/

joomla_root/joomla/user/ (authentication.php)**

In addition, you need to change all references to "username" to "e-mail", and to do that I suggest you make a change in the language localization file which can be found here:
**joomla_root/language/en-GB/**